# How to replace a specific line in textarea?

Tags: jquery, replace, textarea

I'm trying to replace just one line in a textarea

I'm trying to change that line so it is updated when a selection is made elsewhere on the same form.

I thought it may be best to read the textarea into an array, amend the array element as needed and then write this back to the text area.

This works, but I'm appending it to the current values, not replacing them.

How do I replace them ?

or is there a better way to do this ?

This is the text area:

```
<textarea  name="msg" id="msg"  style="height: 150px; width: 300px;">
first line is OK
sendline is also fine

new val=
this line is fine    
</textarea>
```

The line I want to replace is `new val=`
and I'm trying to replace that with `new val=` and the value from `$('#test').val();`

This is the jquery I have so far:

```
$('#test').on('change', function() {
    var test = $(this).val();      
    var lines = $('#msg').val().split(/\n/);
    lines[2] = "new val= " + test;
    $.each(lines , function(i, val) { 
        $("#msg").append("\r\n" + lines[i]);
    })
```

and a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84pk258r/)** showing what it's doing.

any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `.html()` to add the lines to the textarea or emty it first.
Also you are not changing the correct line index and there is no need to loop through the lines with `.each()` you can simply use `.join()`.

Here is a working example:

```js
$(function(){
  
    $('#test').on('change', function() {
        var test = $(this).val();      
        var lines = $('#msg').val().split(/\n/);
        lines[3] = "new val= " + test;
        $("#msg").html(lines.join("\n"));
    });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='test' name='test'>
    <option value='1234'>1234</option>
    <option value='3456'>3456</option>
    <option value='4445'>4445</option>
</select>    
<br/><br/>

<textarea  name="msg" id="msg"  style="height: 150px; width: 300px;">
first line is OK
sendline is also fine

new val=
this line is fine    
</textarea>
```

Comment: @JeffVader Have fun !

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#msg').html('Message');
```

Use .html() not the append() method.The html method replacs all content between the textarea tag with your new message.

The .append() method is used to add content within an element

example

```
<div id="content">
<p>Hello World</p>
</div>

.append() will add new content inside <div>
.html() will replace the content inside the <div>
```

UPDATE

```
<script>

$('#test').on('change', function() {
            var test = $(this).val();      
            var lines = $('#msg').text().split(/\n/);
            lines[3] = "new val= " + test;
            $('#msg').html("");
            $.each(lines , function(i, val) { 

                $("#msg").append("\r\n" + lines[i]);
            }); 
        });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/84pk258r/1/

Hi check the updated code works fine now!

Comment: .html() is what I thought I needed. But using that just changes '#msg' to show `new val=`the value from `$('#test').val();` but not the rest of the text that was in there,

Any way to do that ?